# Avoiding configuration drift

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I run 11 Windows 2008 R2 x64 servers. I am looking at a way to manage and avoid configuration drift. Does anyone know any tools that could help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what configuration you're talking about. If the servers are part of a domain, define settings that apply to all the servers in a Group Policy Object instead of manually configuring the settings on each server.

Comment: Really what I want to avoid is that I place a common set of files on each server (Eg command line tools) and then they disappear from one server with no trace.

Comment: Again it depends. If the tools that you're talking about have MSI installers, then you can assign the package to all the servers via a Group Policy. If you're manually copying a folder full of executables into a certain place on your servers, you could host that folder on a DC and the use Group Policy Preferences to specify the source and destination, so if they're ever deleted they will be restored.